# I deployed to Azure App Service on FTPS. But I can't find those files by WebSSH

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

First, I deployed to Azure App Service on FTPS by FileZilla.

[image: deploy]

Next, I found those files by WebSSH.
But I can find a default file only.

[image: WebSSH]

I wanna deploy to Azure App Service. What should I do?

(My English isn't good, so sorry if I'm wrong)

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that both the FTP and the WebSSH session that you used do, in fact, point to the same site?

Comment: Sorry. I'd like to know how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to connect Azure App Service using FTP-FileZilla application like below.**

[image]

> Make sure Create your web application with required privileges to authenticate with FTP

I have created web applications with required configuration like below.

**Azure Portal > App Service > Create**

[image]

Once create the App service, check the web application running status

**Azure Portal > App Service > Overview > Browse**

[image]

**Connect your App service using FTP-FileZilla Application**

[Install](https://download.filezilla-project.org/client/FileZilla_3.62.2_win64_sponsored2-setup.exe) FileZilla Application

Open FileZilla Application like below

[image]

[image]

Download **Publish Profile** from Azure App Service

**Azure Portal > App Service > Overview > Get Publish profile**

[image]

Once download the Publish Profile and Open the file with Notepad or Notepad++ and copy the **Publish URL** and FTP **username** and **Password** to connect FileZilla Application like below,

[image]

**Username and Password**

[image]

**Connect to App service like below.**

[image]

Once I connect to **App Service** via **FileZilla** able to view the default Files in **wwwroot** folder

[image]

Modified **hostingstart.html** file like below.

[image]